# Amazon MWS unable to update minimum/maximum prices with right currency format

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to set Standardm, Minimum and Maximum prices for our products on Amazon via MWS Feeds API. Could someone help me, please? Here is my XML and error from amazon. 
I am trying update price market for germany, espanol, italy and others market for EU.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>MY_ID_FOR_AMAZON</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Price>
    <SKU>EFR-550D-1AVUEF</SKU>
    <StandardPrice currency="EUR">212,55</StandardPrice>
    <MinimumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">191,30</MinimumSellerAllowedPrice>
    <MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">233,81</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice>
    </Price>
    </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Error from Amazon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>MY_ID_FOR_AMAZON</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>53036017422</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>2</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>2</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>5000</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>XML Parsing Error at Line 2, Column 453: cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element &apos;StandardPrice&apos; must have no element [children], and the value must be valid.</ResultDescription>
                <AdditionalInfo>
                    <SKU>DW-6900-1</SKU>
                </AdditionalInfo>
            </Result>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>5000</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>XML Parsing Error at Line 2, Column 453: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: &apos;124,01&apos; is not a valid value for &apos;decimal&apos;.</ResultDescription>
                <AdditionalInfo>
                    <SKU>DW-6900-1</SKU>
                </AdditionalInfo>
            </Result>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>2</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>5000</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>XML Parsing Error at Line 2, Column 778: cvc-complex-type.2.2: Element &apos;StandardPrice&apos; must have no element [children], and the value must be valid.</ResultDescription>
                <AdditionalInfo>
                    <SKU>EFR-550D-1AVUEF</SKU>
                </AdditionalInfo>
            </Result>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>2</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>5000</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>XML Parsing Error at Line 2, Column 778: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: &apos;212,55&apos; is not a valid value for &apos;decimal&apos;.</ResultDescription>
                <AdditionalInfo>
                    <SKU>EFR-550D-1AVUEF</SKU>
                </AdditionalInfo>
            </Result>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

xsd here: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/Price.xsd

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the API, but a quick Google showed me some XML, and they use a `.` and not a `,` in their prices https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=47878

```
<Price>
    <SKU>MYTEST_1Z-500ABR-FLAT</SKU>
    <StandardPrice currency="EUR">10000.00</StandardPrice>
</Price>
```

Comment: Same problem but another error 90111: `The Message/Price/MaximumSellerAllowedPrice field contains an invalid value: 142.61. The value "142.61" is not a valid CURRENCY.</`

Comment: 'The Message/Price/MaximumSellerAllowedPrice field contains an invalid value: 142.61. The value "142.61" is not a valid CURRENCY.'

Comment: Can you find the docs for that exact XML? I had trouble finding the exact one you were using

Comment: I have just this information [link](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html) FEED: _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_

Comment: great. which feed is it?

Comment: _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_

Answer (score 0):

Pricing feed XSD [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/Price.xsd)

Amazon Based XSD [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/amzn-base.xsd)

While the `StandardPrice` is specified in the .xsd as a `OverrideCurrencyAmount`, the
`MinimumSellerAllowedPrice` and `MaximumSellerAllowedPrice` are specified as `StringOverrideCurrencyAmount`.

It's not obvious from the xsd but what I've found this means in practice is that the `StandardPrice` has to always be in xxxx.xx format but the max and min prices need to be in a localised format eg xxxx,xx for EUR prices and xxxx.xx for GBP prices